# Can't use inbound email on localhost

Tags: php, rest, email, post, mandrill

So as I assume, everyone use a local stack for development. Now here's my issue, my project heavily relies on inbound-emails. And to do this, I planned on using Mandrill. The issue with them is I couldn't figure out a way to get emails passed to localhost. So I then tried MailGun. Same issue. It all appears that I need an actual domain and host to use inbound emails. I don't mind doing that, the issue is, its development and I'd much rather prefer using a local stack. Any ideas on how I can work around this? So to sum it up, all I want to do is accept inbound email to my localhost. So maybe `anything@localhost.com`? Is this how it works?

Comment: you need (at least) a running mail server to receive mails in your computer, so no it's not that easy. Maybe if you give us more information on what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Well I have Postfix, because it came with MAMP. I'm just trying to parse incoming emails. But I need to do it on localhost @mTorres

Comment: So, to make this work in your local machine, you'll also need a DNS server and create a fake domain with an MX record pointing to the private IP of your local machine. Your network settings must use this DNS server in order to resolve the mail server for this fake domain. You'll also need to configure the postifx mailserver so, all in all it won't be easy at all, tough doable... Maybe you can try using the [gmail php api client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), this way you can send mails to your gmail account and you can read it from there directly...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your own mail server - that's kind of the point of using Mandrill.

1. get yourself a cheap domain name (eg example.com)
2. create some MX records for the domain pointing at Mandrill for inbound mail processing (see examples on Inbound Domain settings in Mandrill) ... eg "example.com => 10  1111111.in1.mandrillapp.com" (use what Mandrill tells you to use)
3. create an A record for the domain pointing at the public IP address of your network (eg www.example.com => 1.1.1.1 ... change 1.1.1.1 to your public IP address)
4. poke a hole in your firewall (ie set up port forwarding) which forwards inbound traffic on port 8080 (or similar) to your MAMP server (or whatever you use locally).
5. configure your MAMP server to respond to traffic on that domain/port/whatever you set up
6. test you can access your MAMP server by browsing to the domain name you configured (eg. http://www.example.com:8080/foo ... assuming you have something at /foo on your MAMP server). Test this from an external network if possible to make sure non-local machines can connect.
7. configure a webhook in Mandrill to point to the address of your PHP script on your MAMP server (eg http://www.example.com:8080/mandrill.php)
8. use the "send test" button next to the webhook in Mandrill to test your code

The only magic here is the "poking a hole in your firewall (port forwarding)" bit. This is not related to Mandrill and doesn't require Mandrill to work ... all Mandrill is doing is POSTing data to whatever URL you tell it to. We just want that URL to be pointing to your local MAMP server - which is where the port forwarding bit comes in.

If you can't configure the port forwarding to the point of being able to use a different network to connect to your local MAMP (eg your phone connected to the internet via 3G/4G and not via WiFi to your local networK), then none of this will work.